# Set multiple priorities to an Enum | JAVA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8, enums

The flow for my states is as given below. Where A, B, C, D, X are states that are used as enums.

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E

    A -> X  
    B -> X
    C -> X
    D -> X
```

The arrows meaning the state is reachable. i.e. A -> X means A can reach X but not vice versa.
The way I am implementing is :

```
public enum States{
    A(0), B(1), C(2), D(3);
    private int priority;
    …
    }
```

There is a floating state X, which is reachable from A, B, C and D.
I want to set the priority of X in the way as above. Is there a way to do so? i,e. Set multiple priorities to a single enum.

Comment: Only if you write the code for it.  I'm not sure what you're asking -- you've designed your own priority system, so you will have to implement it in a way that works for your use case.  You certainly can't set an int to multiple values, so you will have to adjust your design at least somewhat.

Comment: With "floating state" do you mean a state that's not one of the enum values? How would your code handle the enum as well as another class at the same time? Do they have a common interface or do you need to check the type all the time? Btw, I'm not sure an `int` is the best way to express a unidirectional "flow".

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using integers to define a graph, especially if it is unidirectional, I'd suggest you actually use references.

However, since enum values can only reference already existing ones in their constructors, you'd either have to declare the dependency backwards or use an initializer block.

**"backwards":**

```
//backwards dependency
enum State {
  A,
  B(A),
  C(B),
  D(C),
  X(A,B,C,D);

  private List<State> successors = new ArrayList<>();

  private State(State... predecessors) {
    Arrays.stream(predecessors).forEach(p -> p.successors.add(this));
  }

  ...
}

//backwards declaration
enum State {
  X,
  D(X),
  C(D,X),
  B(C,X),
  A(B,X);

  private List<State> successors;

  private State(State... successors ) {
    this.successors = List.of(successors);
  }

  ...
}
```

**static initializer**

```
enum State {
  A,B,C,D,X;

  private List<State> successors = new ArrayList<>();

  static {
    A.successors.addAll(List.of(B,X));
    B.successors.addAll(List.of(C,X));
    C.successors.addAll(List.of(D,X));
    D.successors.addAll(List.of(X));
  }

  ...
}
```

If `X` is not part of the enum you'd need to define a common interface and use that as the type for `successors`.